# Visual studio code nodejs debugging not working

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, visual-studio-code

i am new to using visual studio code and trying to debugg node application. I have generated the launch.json file and it is as following :

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/app.js"
        }
    ]
```

and here is the method which is I am trying to debug, it is inside testController.js :

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Site Home Page');
};
```

I have also added this controller to route and added the route to express app as following :

test.js

```
const express = require('express');

    const router = express.Router();

    var test_controller = require('../controllers/testController');

    router.get('/',test_controller.index);

    module.exports = router;
```

and app.js :

```
var index = require('./routes/test');
//Add routes middlewares
app.use('/',index);
```

I have added the breakpoint to `exports.index`.The problem when I hit the debugging button it directly hits the breakpoint but when I call the same route from Postman to test api, it never hits the breakpoint. Any suggestion.

Comment: Is your breakpoint is on `res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Site Home Page');` or on `exports.index = function(req, res) {` ?. If its on `exports.index = function(req, res) {` try to put it on `res.send`

Comment: thanks @kgangadhar. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breakpoints you put on method definitions will hit during the server start while launching, Where as the breakpoints added on the lines within the method will hit when the methods are being called.

In your case you added breakpoints to `exports.index = function(req, res) {` instead of `res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Site Home Page')`;. When you hit the debugging button its hitting and on calling same method, inside lines are not hitting. Make sure you added breakpoints to the lines you want to  check.